# Ordinary generating function for Bernoulli polynomial

Tags: analysis, number-theory, special-functions

I know the exponential generating function for the Bernoulli polynomial $B_n(x)$:$$\frac{te^{tx}}{e^t-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}.$$
But is there an ordinary generating function? i.e a function $f$ such that $$f(t,x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n(x)t^n$$ valid for some open interval of $x$ and some open interval of $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The exponential generating function has a pole at $t = 2 \pi i$, so for any $x$, $B_n(x)$ grows at least as fast as about $\frac{n!}{(2\pi)^n}$, hence the ordinary generating function has zero radius of convergence in $t$.

When possible, you can convert exponential generating functions to ordinary ones using a variant of the [Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should actually be able to express this generating function in terms of *polygamma functions*. In particular, we notice that an *ordinary* (yes, very atypical) generating function for the Bernoulli numbers following from Borel summation (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Newtonian_series)) is given in terms of $\psi^{(1)}(z)$ (the *trigamma function*) as 
$$\widetilde{B}(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} B_n z^n = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{z}{(zk+1)^2} = \frac{1}{z} \psi_1(1/z)-z.$$
Now we can easily see from the *binomial transform* that 
$$B_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} B_k x^{n-k} = x^n \cdot [z^n] \frac{1}{1-xz} \widetilde{B}\left(-\frac{z}{x(1-z)}\right) = [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} \widetilde{B}\left(-\frac{z}{1-xz}\right).$$ 
So your desired ordinary generating function is expressed as 
$$\frac{1}{1-xz}\left[\frac{xz-1}{z} \psi_1\left(\frac{xz-1}{z}\right) + \frac{z}{1-xz}\right].$$