# Proper Bernoulli Function Generating Function

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, power-series, generating-functions, bernoulli-numbers

Consider the function

$$\frac{t}{e^t - 1} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_i}{i!}t^i$$

This has been one of the famous generating functions for the bernoulli numbers. What about the function associated with

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}B_it^i$$

What function could this be?

Comment: you mean in terms elementary functions like $e^x, \ln x, \sin x, \cdots$

Comment: Is the solution not elementary? If so, are there any recurrence/differential equations it obeys etc??? Any information would be nice in this regard, as I haven't found anything regarding it

Comment: 1) Do you want Bernoulli _numbers_ or _functions_? Your title and question are at odds there. 2) Rephrasing your question in the usual terminology: the _exponential_ GF of the Bernoulli numbers is well-known; what about the _ordinary_ GF? For the Bernoulli polynomials, this has been discussed in this older answered [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/370985/137524). So this may be a duplicate...

Comment: Then it appears to be a duplicate. I believe I meant Bernoulli numbers (which as the bernoulli polynomials of argument 0?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such a generating function use this asymptotic expansion of the ["digamma function" $\psi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Computation_and_approximation) :

$$-\left(\psi\left(\frac 1x\right)+\log x+\frac x2\right)\sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2n}}{2n}x^{2n},\quad \text{as}\;x\to 0$$
The origin of this is simply the [well known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values) $\;\zeta(1-n)=-\dfrac{B_n}n\;$ applied to the Euler Maclaurin expansion of the harmonic sum $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{1/x}\frac 1n$ as shown in the Wikipedia digamma link.

An equivalent formulation is (since $B_1=-\frac 12$ is the only non zero odd Bernoulli number)
$$\tag{1}-\left(\psi\left(\frac 1x\right)+\log x+x\right)\sim \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k}x^{k},\quad \text{as}\;x\to 0$$
Computing the derivative of $(1)$, multiplying by $x$ and adding $1$ (since $B_0=1$) we finally get :

$$\tag{2} \frac{\psi'\left(\frac 1x\right)}x-x\sim \sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k\; x^{k},\quad \text{as}\;x\to 0$$
(with $\psi'$ the [trigamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function#Calculation) and the relation also provided in the link)

Comment: So then is there a way to write: $$\frac{2}{3} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^i \frac{\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})}{\Gamma(i)\Gamma(\frac{3}{2}-i)}B_i x^{(\frac{3}{2}-i)}}$$ in terms of the polygamma functions

Comment: I believe this expression equals $$ \sum_{i=1}^{x}{i^{\frac{1}{2}}} $$

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: Well $\;\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}\,$ and  $\;\Gamma(1/2-i)=\dfrac{(-4)^i\,i!}{(2i)!}\sqrt{\pi}\;$ from [gamma's properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) (btw the last formula for $\;\Gamma(1/2-i)$ is wrong ; it should be a Pochhammer symbol I think!) so that 

$$\frac{(-1)^i\;\Gamma\bigl(\frac{3}{2}\bigr)}{\Gamma(i)\Gamma\bigl(\frac{3}{2}-i\bigr)}=\frac {\frac 12 (2i)!}{(i-1)!\bigl(\frac{1}{2}-i\bigr)\;4^i\,i!}=\frac{i}{(2i-1)\,4^i}\binom{2i}{i}$$

Comment: Multiplying this by a Bernoulli number will give you something rather more complicated than the simple $B_i\,x^i$ from my answer I fear... For some equalities and generating functions for central binomial coefficients you may look at this [link](http://www.pi314.net/eng/hypergse11.php) but here we have the additional Bernoulli coefficient. I didn't verify your last equality yet (I have to go...) but the expansion of sqrt will usually provide these central binomial terms.

Comment: that is my motivation. I was considering how to generalize $$\sum_{i=0}^{x}[i^s]  $$ which I has a relationship with the bernoulli numbers, so i extended the formula where i ranges from 0 to infinity (which doesn't change its value) but now makes sense for non-integral x. Yielding the previously mentioned formula for the sum of the square roots. Somehow I felt that understanding the behavior of the bernoulli generating function would make things clearer

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: Ok so you want to generalize the [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) to non integer powers. This finite sum may in fact be rewritten as a difference of two [Hurwitz zeta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) as shown in this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X04003816) or in [MathWorld's "Power sum"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html) : $$\sum_{i=0}^{x}i^s=\zeta(-s,1)-\zeta(-s,x+1)$$ (let's be clear : this is a mere rewriting of your sum as you may see from the zeta definition)

Comment: Concerning approximations this [paper](http://webpages.ursinus.edu/kmcgown/preprints/Bernoulli_Elemente_Preprint.pdf) may too be of interest.

Comment: Of course D. Knuth's 1993 paper ["Johann Faulhaber and sums of powers"](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1993-61-203/S0025-5718-1993-1197512-7/S0025-5718-1993-1197512-7.pdf) shoudn't be missed! Excellent explorations,